# Unzipping epub - End of Central Directory record could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to open an epub stored on the external SD card in WP8, using the Microsoft Compression package for windows phone. However, I get the following exception:

`System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()`

I tried copying the epubs off my phone to my computer, and I can open them as ziparchives there without any problem, so I don't believe that the epubs are corrupt.

This is my code:

```
ExternalStorageDevice _sdCard = (await ExternalStorage.GetExternalStorageDevicesAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
    ExternalStorageFile file = await _sdCard.GetFileAsync(path);
    if (file != null)
    {
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(await file.OpenForReadAsync(), ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(entry.Name);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && fileName.EndsWith("content.opf"))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/c-sharp-end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found) 
There could be a possibility that there are multiple parts in the archive.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but I noticed that you have the name of the opf file hard-coded. The opf file can be named anything in an epub file and still be standards-compliant. In order to determine the name of the opf file, one should check the contents of the META-INF/container.xml entry in the epub archive which should be the second entry in the zip file right behind a mimetype file entry. More information about the standards can be found at http://idpf.org/epub/201 for epub2 and http://idpf.org/epub/30 for epub3