# Read .xlsx Excel File error

Tags: c#, xlsx, worksheet, import-from-excel

Hi I've Error while reading .xlsx Excle file. I'm using Excel.dll and when I'm trying to read data from my worksheet I'm getting error

> "End of Central Directory record could not be found."

Here's sample code

```
foreach (var worksheet in Workbook.Worksheets(@"c:\MyFile.xlsx"))
```

Comment: Have you tried using another xlsx file. Does this happens for all xlsx file or a particular one?

Comment: it seems that your xlsx file is not valid, please have a look at the following link, it may help you solve the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/c-sharp-end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that my .xlsx was protected by password so I used different one, now it 's working.