# C# Xamarin android "Central Directory record could not be found"

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Following issue occurs when building the project.

**Output Window Details**

```
*1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: XYZ.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\amila.s\Desktop\XYZ\ABC.Mobile-develop\ABC.Mobile-develop\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(114,3): error : End of Central Directory record could not be found.
1>C:\Users\amila.s\Desktop\XYZ\ABC.Mobile-develop\ABC.Mobile-develop\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(114,3): error :    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
1>C:\Users\amila.s\Desktop\XYZ\ABC.Mobile-develop\ABC.Mobile-develop\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(114,3): error :    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
1>C:\Users\amila.s\Desktop\XYZ\ABC.Mobile-develop\ABC.Mobile-develop\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(114,3): error :    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
1>C:\Users\amila.s\Desktop\XYZ\ABC.Mobile-develop\ABC.Mobile-develop\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(114,3): error :    at Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore.LoadResource(String resourceFullPath, String assemblyName)
1>C:\Users\amila.s\Desktop\XYZ\ABC.Mobile-develop\ABC.Mobile-develop\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(114,3): error :    at Xamarin.Build.Download.BaseXamarinBuildResourceRestore.MergeResources(IAssemblyResolver resolver, String originalAsmPath, String mergedAsmPath, String assemblyName, List`1 resourceItems)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========*
```

**Error Window Details**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     End of Central Directory record could not be found.    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode
>   mode, Boolean leaveOpen)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode
>   mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)    at
>   Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore.LoadResource(String
>   resourceFullPath, String assemblyName)    at
>   Xamarin.Build.Download.BaseXamarinBuildResourceRestore.MergeResources(IAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, String originalAsmPath, String mergedAsmPath, String
>   assemblyName, List`1 resourceItems)   PayByCar.Droid

**There are seem to be no much support regarding this issue. It would be highly appreciated if anyone could help on this. Thanks.**

Comment: How did it happen? Can you tell me how to reproduce this problem? And what have you searched and tried?

Comment: I am not doing anything special.
1 . I have setup the VS Professional latest version with android SDK
2.  Then I import the Xamarin project.
3.  After that just right click and build the project.

This is the way for the recreate this issue.

Note : I am beginner for Xamarin.
 
Thanx joe.

Comment: Hi, what have you [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/c-sharp-end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Hi Joe, I am not doing zip kind of things programmatically. i think this is happening when downloading packages. it is on project initial build. Thanx.

Comment: @AmilaSenevirathna - did you get a solution for this? We're getting the same error on a new Visual Studio/Xamarin install. I suspect that one of the components (downloaded as a zip) is corrupt. But _which_ one?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else is getting this issue as well, (And cannot simply do like what a lot of other threads recommend, by changing the version of Xamarin.Build.Download to a previous version):

My solution was to go to *C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local* and delete the Xamarin and XamarinBuildDownloadCache, then rebuild my project.

I presume that due to a faulty network connection, one or more files had been corrupted during the initial download process, which made it so that even clearing just about everything (except that directory) would not fix the issue.