# Is there way to specify local file system path in nodeJS POST API request , am able to make api call using curl but not with nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, rest, azure-functions, nodejs-stream

Following curl API is successfully deploying .zip file from the local file system into the Azure Function APP.

curl -X POST -u user123:P@ssword --data-binary @"C:\Ddrive\Porject\deploy-zip\wb-uc-code.zip" "https://abc-world.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"

### But I wanna achieve the same with NodeJs: So I converted it as -

function () {

```
var dataString = "@C:\Ddrive\Workbench\deploy-zip\wb-uc1.zip";

var options = {
    url: 'https://abc-world.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString,
    auth: {
        'user': 'user123',
        'pass': 'P@ssword'
    }
};

request.post(options, (response, error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error");
    }
    else {
        console.log(response.body);
    }
})
```

### }

while executing am getting error:
[image]
------->>>
Most Probably I think am unable to provide file-path appropriately in **Options**. Can someone help with this?

Comment: See: https://github.com/request/request#streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to pay attention to.

1.You should pass **data-binary**, you were passing path string in your code.

2.The order of **response** and **error** is reversed.

Please refer to the working code as below.

```
var request=require('request')
var fs = require("fs")

var dataString=fs.createReadStream("D:\\testProject\\NodeJs\\nodejs-docs-hello-world\\test4.zip");

var options = {
    url: 'https://tonytestwebnode.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString,
    auth: {
        'user': 'tonytestweb',
        'pass': 'XXXX!'
    }
};

request.post(options, (error, response) => {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, That error got resolved but deployment was unsuccessful, I am getting 500 error code but the same is getting deployed with curl.

Comment: @GKAMESWARRAO What is the detailed error message? Is the password correct?

Comment: Yes I checked file-path it is correct and  I believe your code is also correct. Are you able to deploy the file in Azure AppService? Am trying to deploy function App through this URL, though it gets deployed by curl while trying to achieve the same with Node am getting an issue.

Comment: @GKAMESWARRAO Yes, I deployed an webapp successfully. You need to check the detailed error message.

Comment: Am getting the following error: 500
BODY: -->  {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"End of Central Directory record could not be found.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.InvalidDataException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.Pu\

Comment: @GKAMESWARRAO Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found