# NET Core throws InvalidDataException when unzipping ZIP file, Windows Explorer unzips successfully

Tags: c#, .net-core, zip, unzip, c#-ziparchive

I'm trying to unzip a nested zip file, but I'm getting a `InvalidDataException`.  When I try unzipping the same file in Windows Explorer, it unzips successfully.  Why would Windows Explorer be able to unzip it and not the .NET Core Compression library?

I suspect there is something wrong with the zip file, but if Windows Explorer is able to do it, it must be possible to do in a .NET Core project.

I've tried unzipping the parent zip file, but that throws the `InvalidDataException 'A local file header is corrupt.'`

```csharp
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("parent.zip", outputFolder) // throws exception
```

I've tried opening the parent zip file and unzipping the nested zip file, but that also throws the `InvalidDataException 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.'`

```csharp
using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead("parent.zip"))
{
    var nestedZip = archive.GetEntry("nested.zip");
    
    using (var stream = nestedZip.Open())
    using (var nestedArchive = new Archive(stream)) // throws exception
    {
        nestedArchive.ExtractToDirectory(outputFolder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Windows might be able to uncompress it fine, but are the files actually OK and intact?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [End of Central Directory record could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found)

Comment: @mxmissile there are a lot of files in the zip, but the few I've opened looked ok.  I've had issues where files were corrupt in the zip file, but it doesn't throw an exception when creating the ZipArchive object, only when extracting an ZipArchiveEntry

Comment: @Marshal I saw that question, but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Try the scenario with a different zip file and see if that works, if it works means that there's some issue with the zip file.

Also try using a different librairy.

Comment: it work's with other zip files, so I do think the issue is with the zip file, but that begs the question, why is Windows still able to unzip the file? And how can I replicate it in code?

Comment: `why is Windows still able to unzip the file` Presumably it is not calling that same code.