# Unzip created zip folder to same folder?

Tags: c#, unzip

Many thanks for the support. I am trying to copy a zip folder and create folder location from a specified pathway, to another pathway then unzip the folder.

The creation part works fine I can create the zip from a specified location to a new specified location, but when I come to unzip it, it tells me the folder is in use. This makes sense but I am unsure of another way to unzip it once it has been created. I have checked other questions and methods, but none seem to have the answer or work. I am sure there are much easier ways to do this (code below):

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ZipWorker
{
    public class FolderCreate
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string pathInput;
            string pathString;

            // Define creation location for update files. Loop continuously until path is entered.
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path for the creation of the Folder");
                pathString = Console.ReadLine();
                pathString = pathString.Replace("\"", "");

            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathString));

            // Define location of upgrade zip file to copy. Loop continuously until path is entered. 
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path for the Folder to copy");
                pathInput = Console.ReadLine();
                pathInput = pathInput.Replace("\"", "");

            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathInput));

            // Create the folder path. You can verify in File Explorer that you have this e.g.
            // structure in the C: drive.
            //    Local Disk (C:)
            //        Top-Level Folder
            //            SubFolder
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

            // Create a file name for the upgrade zip file you want to create.Based off user console input.
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pathInput);
            // This example uses an string for the name. You can specify any file in the console.

            // Combine to add the upgrade file name to the path.
            pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);

            // Verify the path that you have constructed.
            Console.WriteLine("Path to my file: {0}\n", pathString);

            // Check that the file doesn't already exist. If it doesn't exist, create
            // DANGER: System.IO.File.Create will overwrite the file if it already exists.
            // This could happen even with random file names, although it is unlikely.
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
            {
                System.IO.File.Create(pathString);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(pathString,pathString);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File \"{0}\" already exists.", fileName);
                return;
            }
            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
    // Sample output:

// Path to my file: c:\Top-Level Folder\SubFolder\ttxvauxe.vv0
```

```
// ****Updated 15/02/21 with replace statement***:

using System;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ZipWorker
{
    class FolderCreate
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string pathInput;
            string pathString;

            // Define creation location for update files. Loop continuously until path is entered.
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path for the folder that you want to create");
                pathString = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathString));

            // Define location of upgrade zip file to copy. Loop continuously until path is entered. 
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path for the Folder to copy");
                pathInput = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathInput));

            if (pathString.Contains("\"") || pathInput.Contains("\""))
            {
                pathString = pathString.Replace("\"", "");
                pathInput = pathString.Replace("\"", "");
            }

            // Create the folder path. You can verify in File Explorer that you have this e.g.
            // structure in the C: drive.
            //    Local Disk (C:)
            //        Top-Level Folder
            //            SubFolder
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

            // Creates a file path and removes .zip from folder name, for the upgrade zip file you want to install. Based off user console input. 
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pathInput);
            if (fileName.Contains(".zip"))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Replace(".zip", "");
            }
            // This example uses an release string for the name. You can specify any file in the console.

            // Combine to add the upgrade file name to the path.
            pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);

            // Verify the path that you have constructed.
            Console.WriteLine("Path to my file: {0}\n", pathString);

            // Check that the file doesn't already exist. If it doesn't exist, create
            // DANGER: System.IO.File.Create will overwrite the file if it already exists.
            // This could happen even with random file names, although it is unlikely.
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(pathInput, pathString);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File \"{0}\" already exists.", fileName);
                return;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```
****\\ I've spotted the error I was referencing the same variable in my if statement

if (pathString.Contains("\"") || pathInput.Contains("\""))
            {
                pathString = pathString.Replace("\"", "");
                pathInput = pathString.Replace("\"", "");
            }

\\ This should have been pathInput = pathInput sorted now.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is a .zip file that should work. I tried this in a rar file that gave me error [System.IO.Invalid Data Exception] for checking that error you can go to that link.

[End of Central Directory record could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found)

You are trying to unzip a file(.zip extension) to a File folder. That is what i understood from your question but in your code you gave a file location which has a .zip extension. It needs to be a File folder.
I made some changes check this one.

```
namespace ZipWorker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string pathInput;
            string pathString;

            
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path for the folder that you want to create");
                pathString = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathString));

            
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path for the Folder to copy");
                pathInput = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathInput));

            
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

            
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pathInput);
            if (fileName.Contains(".zip"))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Replace(".zip", "");
            }
            
            pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName) ;

            
            Console.WriteLine("Path to my file: {0}\n", pathString);
            
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(pathInput, pathString);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File \"{0}\" already exists.", fileName);
                return;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this will give it a try and let you know :)

Comment: Hi , So this partially works. The issue I am having is I need to remove quotes from the pathway when a user pastes in the full path. I see you removed that from my code above. I have re-added as an if statement but I now received an access to path is denied :(

Comment: @extarlife Give an example of what's the path used

Comment: Hi @Martheen for example "C:\Users\username\Downloads\somefile.zip" if this is copied and pasted as part of the "Please enter the path for the Folder to copy"  into console, then I need the code to remove the "" otherwise it throws an error.