# Azure App Service Web App Deploy from VScode "Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not..."

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I often have the following error when trying to deploy a Node app to Azure via the VScode Azure App Service extension. I am not sure what it doesn't like about my project. I have looked around and seen related hits to the problem that crack it up to be the fact that I am using a Windows machine and deploying to Linux, and that's why it doesn't like the zip file? In the past I have just avoided the problem by creating a new webapp on Azure to deploy to and it works, but I can never deploy to the same Webapp service twice.

```
10:00:21 AM CardGameServer: Starting deployment...

10:00:21 AM CardGameServer: Creating zip package...

10:02:03 AM CardGameServer: Zip package size: 20.1 kB

10:02:03 AM CardGameServer: Fetching changes.

10:02:04 AM CardGameServer: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/981fc9e6-5778-4a2c-9145-02463df858a7.zip (0.02 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted

10:02:04 AM CardGameServer: Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.
10:02:10 AM CardGameServer: Deployment failed.
```

Also the "Creating zip package..." step takes about 4 minutes. The app is 20kb (as seen in the console output). Why does this take so long? Sometimes it even times out. Does it push my entire workspace to azure and zip it there?
If I don't have a ignore pattern for the node_modules I get a zip with size 182mb in the output console, and it takes just as long to deploy as when node_modules is ignored.(I run npm install via the `.deployment` file with `"SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true" so I ignore the node_modules folder).
The file count mismatch error occurs whether or not I have ZipIgnorePatterns specified, or if using only the "default" ignore patterns of `"node_modules{,/**}", ".vscode{,/**}"`

I thought I read somewhere on a Microsoft doc (trying to track down that page - it was a highlighted warning box on the page) that the web app publishing extension fails with apps that are apart of repos that have a large number of commits.

My workspace:
[image: workspace]

Deployment settings:
[image]

Comment: I have just started getting the same issue. Let me know if you solve it!

Comment: I also faced this wired issue. Then I deleted the app, deployed using local git following [their official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash) And it worked.

Comment: @RiddleRiddlerRddler I will. Currently I've mitigated the problem by using Docker deploy instead. I created a docker image that has the app. Uploaded to docker hub, and then pulled it into Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deploy through VS Code would push your entire workspace to azure with an zip package, and extract not zip them on Azure.

About `Creating zip package...` step, it seems something going wrong with your project. Actually it should take some time for compressing your entire project, and the `Zip package size` should not be so small.

As I can see, your `zipIgnorepattern` is too much. Maybe some file you set ignore is required. **Just let the `settings.json` file to be default and try to deploy again.**

I have a simple node project and deploy it through VS Code successfully:
[image]

And this is the file structure on Azure kudu site:
[image]
My default `settings.json`:
[image]

Comment: that's exactly what my settings.json file looks like, and I have the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the fact that  the Azure Web App extension uploads the entire workspace. The zip mismatch file count error occurs with or without a `zipIgnorePattern` specified for my workspace. I added the patterns in an attempt to solve the problem (to see if it was complaining about a file in particular). My web app is only 20kb ( 5 or 6 small js files, and of course the package.json). I ended up putting it in a docker and uploading the docker to docker hub and setting up Azure with continuous deploy.

Comment: I still would like to use the Azure web app extension though. I am going to attempt to use the CLI to manually add the zip. (If hosting a web app on windows Azure has a drag and drop zip GUI, but only CLI for linux currenty).

Comment: Actually I am confused by your comment on the upload and zipping process. You make it sound like the Azure Web App extension zips and uploads the entire workspace regardless of the ZipIgnorePatterns, and then uses the ZipIgnorePattern to filter out what files to incorporate in the Web Apps root file system? I would think that the ZipIgnorePattern would be used on the local machine and then a zip file absent the files based on the patterns would be uploaded? I've added some more details about settings to my question.

Comment: Could you run your project successfully on your local computer? @TwoFingerRightClick

Comment: Yes it runs fine. To mitigate, I currently deployed it via a docker image on Azure, but I would prefer to use the web app extension in VSCode. This error appears to be a .Net error. So something about the implementation of the zip process in Azure (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found) @DorisLv

Answer (score 0):

Check in Azure if your App Service or Function App is set up under Deployment Center.  We had originally set up the build pipeline and release pipeline through the Azure Deployment Center.  Then when we tried to create a new release pipeline to the same app service we ended up with the error:

```
Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64.
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL
Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

The solution is to go into Azure Portal > App Service (or deployment slot) > Deployment Center and then Disconnect your app.