# 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.' on certain zips

Tags: c#

I have a script that downloads Zips using `httpclient` from a server and extracts them using `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` to a specific folder, it works perfectly except for 4 zips that are bigger than 500 MB. It downloads them successfully but it throws this error when its comes to extracting the zip:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.
```

Weirdly enough, it does work normally on a zip that is bigger than 1GB. I've tried the following:
Rezipping the files
Checking if I can open the zip file in windows
Extracting the zip manually after manually downloading it from the server
All of these worked perfectly, so I'm at a loss on how to fix this error.

Does anyone have a suggestion or fix for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [End of Central Directory record could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960403/end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found)

Comment: @Ergis unfortunately not, I came across that thread but none of the mentioned fixes apply for mine or work